# How to change the MaaS server ip address?

Tags: maas

I'm experiencing MaaS using VirtualBox. I had the MaaS server installed fine based on the wiki. The VirtualBox VM has two network interfaces, eth0 for NAT, eth1 for Host Only. The MaaS server picked eth0, so I followed the wiki instruction to change the MaaS server IP address via the following command,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas
```

The https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS instruction says "You will be prompted for the correct IP address", but I did not get any prompt.

I was able to manually edit `/etc/cobbler/`settings to change the "server" and "next-server" properties to point to the IP for eth1. The added node was able to boot via PXE that leveraged the MaaS server; however, at the end of the boot, the iscsistart is still trying to connect to IP for eth0, hence, it failed to connect, since the DHCP is set to point to the IP for eth1.

Can you help to point out 1) why I didn't get the prompt? 2) how to manually change IP address setting for the iscsi?

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu 14.04 Server

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller
```

Comment: You might want to specify that maas-cluster-controller is for the web admin app and the maas-region-controller is for the PXE boot controller. If your machines are not booting properly off PXE, you want to run the second command only and update the IP address of your server to be on the right interface/subnet.

Answer (score 3):

Running these commands should do it:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas
sudo maas-import-isos --update-settings
```